# Script para voltar para a página anterior atualizada?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom, eu queria algo que fizesse que quando um pessoa clicasse para ir para uma página ela fosse redirecionada para a página anterior.. Mas a página atualiza...

É que eu fiz um pequeno sistema de comentários, quando clico para comentar ele vai para uma página "InsertComment" mas preciso que ele volte para a página original...

Comment: Não deveria ser o caso de redirecionar automaticamente apos o form ser submetido?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Podes fazer isso das seguintes maneiras:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>
```

ou usando:

```
<script>
    document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back</a>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Caso seja de forma automática, após o form ser submetido, metes na página que object form vai abrir object seguinte código:

```
<body onload='window.history.back();'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Outras possibilidades para voltar para a página anterior:

```
history.go(-1);
```

---

```
window.open(document.referrer,'_self');
```

---

```
location.href = document.referrer;
```

---

Exemplos para teste:

```html
<button onclick="history.go(-1);">Voltar 1</button>

<button onclick="location.href = document.referrer;">Voltar 2</button>

<button onclick="window.open(document.referrer,'_self');">Voltar 3</button>
```

#### Referência:

http://www.guj.com.br/t/como-voltar-para-a-pagina-anterior-jsp/153165/3