# Como saber que chamou a tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho duas telas *Listar* e *Filtrar*, ambas são redirecionadas para uma terceira tela chamada *Visualizar*:

Botão Visualizar da tela *Listar*:

```
//ABRE TELA VISUALIZAR
$(document).on('click', '.visualizar', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  var pClienteID = $(this).attr("data-id");
  window.location.href = "/Administrativo/Cliente/Visualizar?pClienteID=" + parseInt(pClienteID);
});
//FIM
```

Botão Visualizar da tela *Filtrar*:

```
//ABRE TELA VISUALIZAR
$(document).on('click', '.visualizar', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  var pClienteID = $(this).attr("data-id");
  window.location.href = "/Administrativo/Cliente/Visualizar?pClienteID=" + parseInt(pClienteID);
});
//FIM
```

Dúvida: Como implemento o botão *Voltar* da tela *Visualizar*?

Comment: Achei um tópico similar aqui no StackOverflow, talvez ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70611/script-para-voltar-para-a-p%C3%A1gina-anterior-atualizada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode implementar esse botão de duas formas, criando o botão e no evento de click utilizar:

`window.location.href = '/Administrativo/Cliente/Listar'`

Para redirecionar para sua action, ou pode utilizar `history.go(-1)` para retornar para página anterior:

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar este script

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back()
}
</script>
```

e chamar ele em seu botão

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">
```

Exemplo:

```js
function goBack() {
    window.history.back()
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Voltar" onclick="goBack()">
```